# How to differentiate between database Vector class and framework Vector class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
# Stores <x, y, z> triplet in database.
class Vector < ActiveRecord::Base
composed_of :vector, :mapping => [%w(x x), %w(y y), %w(z z)]
end

# Immutable vector class.
class Vector
  attr_reader :x, :y, :z

  def initialize(x, y, z)
    @x, @y, @z = x, y, z
  end

  def add(v)
    Vector.new(@x + v.x, @y + v.y, @z + v.z)
  end

  # etc.
end
```

How do I connect and differentiate the two? I believe it's not good idea to only have the AR Vector (and put all the methods and operations there).. is there some pattern I'm missing? I could rename the first to DbVector or something, but I wonder if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Ruby already has a built in [Vector class](http://apidock.com/ruby/Vector). I'd use that.

Then you will need to disambiguate the names, I'd rather go for namespacing them - maybe `DB::Vector`.

Comment: I take it the other way to disambiguate them would be to use a module. Care to explain why do you prefer namespacing over using a module? I actually don't understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @randomguy - Namespacing is a general term for disambiguating identically named classes, variables, etc. by putting them in some sort of hierarchy. A module is a group of reusable code in Ruby which can be used for the purpose of namespacing. In Jakub's example, `DB::Vector` is a class called `Vector` inside a module called `DB`. Ruby will be treat this as a different class from the top level `Vector`.

Comment: Yep. Writing `class DB::Vector` is equivalent to writing `module DB; class Vector`.

Comment: Ah, thanks guys for explaining. I take it that I can write `composed_of :vector, :class_name => "Foo::Vector", :mapping => ...`? ie. the class_name supports namespaces?